# Postgresql "CLUSTER tablename USING indexname;" takes more disk space than table size plus all indexes combined

Tags: postgresql, diskspace, clustered-index

I have a quite large table in the database. Size of table and its indexes are shown in tables below:

```
 table_size 
----------------
 22 GB
```

```
 schemaname | scan_count | tablename |  indexname  | index_size 
------------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------
 public     | 1352665306 | t1        | ind1        | 6686 MB
 public     | 1492127808 | t1        | ind2        | 6587 MB
 public     |    3492322 | t1        | ind3        | 4747 MB
 public     |   71810172 | t1        | ind4        | 4237 MB
 public     |   80547954 | t1        | cluster_ind | 4035 MB
 public     |    3628773 | t1        | ind6        | 3700 MB
```

As you can see, tables size is 22GB. It has 6 different indexes, which take 30GB of space combined.

According to [postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-cluster.html):

> CLUSTER can re-sort the table using either an index scan on the specified index, or (if the index is a b-tree) a sequential scan followed by sorting. It will attempt to choose the method that will be faster, based on planner cost parameters and available statistical information.

> When an index scan is used, a temporary copy of the table is created that contains the table data in the index order. Temporary copies of each index on the table are created as well. Therefore, ***you need free space on disk at least equal to the sum of the table size and the index sizes***.

However, with `df -h` showing that I have 75GB of free space on the partition containing my postgresql data, I still run out of disk space when I try to cluster the table over `cluster_ind` index using the command below:

```
cluster table using cluster_ind;
```

and I face this error:

```
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16385/2165933.3": wrote only 4096 of 8192 bytes at block 394731
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

**Question**: What else is using disk space during clustering other than table size and sum of sizes of its indexes? And how can I estimate this space required to run a CLUSTER command on a table using an index?

Answer (score 1):

That could be the [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html) table.

Use `pg_total_relation_size('table_name')` to get the full size of the table.

Comment: The result of this command is 61GB!! Is it the total size of table only or the table and its indexes?

Comment: Well according to the docs, it is "Total disk space used by the specified table, including all indexes and TOAST data". So I should still be able to run CLUSTER

Comment: It includes the indexes. Perhaps some temp space is used building the indexes.

Comment: How should I know how much space these temp files will take?

Comment: I'm not even sure about the temp files. It is trial and error. Just increase the disk space.